# Adding a new column in my existing dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Original Dataframe is

```
column_one
1 
1
1
45
45
55
55
56

Expected Output
column-new   
i_1
i_1
i_1
i_2
i_2
i_3
i_3
i_4
```

Based on Column-1 I want to add another new column in my dataframe.
Where there is a consecutive values than add 'i' with the same index. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html). From the docs:

> Useful for obtaining a numeric representation of an array when all that matters is identifying distinct values.

So it will encode each new value it encounters as an enumerated type. Afterwards you can simply add the `'i_'` prefix to the `new_col`:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.col1.factorize()[0] + 1).astype(str)
df['new_col'] = 'i_' + df.new_col
```

**Output**

```
    col1 new_col
0     1     i_1
1     1     i_1
2     1     i_1
3    45     i_2
4    45     i_2
5    55     i_3
6    55     i_3
7    56     i_4
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fast this needs to perform, you can look into using [categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) (`dtype="category"`) , as they should be incredibly fast with large data sets.

If you import your data as a `category` data type, this will already determine which are the unique values.

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype('category')
```

From here, you can then implement the leading "i_" and output the category value, remembering to scale up so that you begin with 1 rather than 0:

```
df['newcol1'] = "i_" + (df["col1"].cat.codes + 1).astype(str)
```

**Output**

```
  col1 newcol1
0    1     i_1
1    1     i_1
2    1     i_1
3   45     i_2
4   45     i_2
5   55     i_3
6   55     i_3
7   56     i_4
```

**Timings**

As the code is simply reading the category index, timing the category lookup against the factorize function for a column of 10,000,000 values between 0 and 1000 gives a timing that is far faster for the category approach. This is because you are not calling a function, but instead reading the index.

It should be noted that there is an initial setup overhead involved (also shown for completion), so the factorize function would be better if you are only performing this once.

```
Categoricals: 0 ms
Factorize: 2092 ms
Categoricals Converstion: 3253 ms
```

**Timings Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def timing(label, fn):
    t0 = time.time()
    fn()
    t1 = time.time()
    print '%s: %d ms' % (label, int((t1 - t0) * 1000))


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=(100000000, 1)), columns=["col1"])

df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype('category')

timing('Categoricals', lambda: (df.col1.cat.codes))

timing('Factorize', lambda: (df.col1.factorize()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my expected output